# Pedal design for scale shift in electric guitar before amplification

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal

I have magnetic pickups using Alnico magnets
I plan to shift scale of all strings by an offset, decided by a potentiometer
Is a 555 timer based circuit possible?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a pitch shifter effect?

Comment: The 555 is a timing chip. You would need an MPC (Multi-Processing Chip). Or you could get a picaxe and upload some code :)

Comment: Not 555-based, but a simple digital logic harmony generator is [here](http://www.experimentalistsanonymous.com/diy/Schematics/Vibrato%20and%20Pitch%20Shift/EMM%20Harmony%20Generator.PDF). (I built one of these in the '90s; I would guess the parts can be adapted as it's just basic digital PLLs and flip flops.)  It produces a simple square wave tone that is in harmony with the input signal.  It will only work on one note at a time - no chords.

Answer (score 3):

The type of pickups is irrelevant - you have an electronic signal you wish to analyse and change the frequencies detected.

A 555 timer is not the way to go. You are looking at this the wrong way entirely.

Pitch shift circuits typically use ring modulation or other mechanisms to perform Fourier transformation in the frequency domain.